# Combine JSON with parent name C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have two similar JSON like this.

```
Models.Person Pers = new Models.Person();

string strJSON1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Pers.GetData("1"));
string strJSON2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Pers.GetData("2"));
```

{
"name":"Jane",
"sex":"fema"
}

{
"name":"Bob",
"sex":"male"
}

How to combine two JSON with parent key like below in c#

```
{
 "AAAA": {
   "name":"Jane",
   "sex":"male"
 },
 "BBBB": {
  "name":"Jane",
  "sex":"male"
 }
}
```

Comment: Why not have List<Models.Person> and then the json will be given to you as expected?  If you don't understand List search c# generics.

Comment: Is "AAAA" supposed to be some kind of index or a "key" string? If the latter, you can serialize a `Dictionary<string,Models.Person>`.

Comment: aah yes using Dictionary. Thx @Fildor